# Regex matching a set of characters on a given index

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and a position in this string. I want to find out if the last non space character before this position is one of the characters in a given set. Can I do this using regex? I couldn't figure it out on my own.

Example with a set of characters (?, |, !):

`foo('blah? test', pos=6) is True`

`foo('blah? test', pos=7) is False`

Comment: It is certainly possible to do this with regex... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your index positions don't match up with the results.

Comment: Is `pos` 0-indexed?

Comment: Index 6 should be `t` in `test`. It's 0-indexed.

Comment: @T.Poe how is the result True for index 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from Regex:

```
In [93]: def is_matched(text, pos, chars='?|!'): 
    ...:     text = text[:pos] 
    ...:     matched = re.search(r'.*(\S)(?=\s*$)', text) 
    ...:     return matched.group(1) in chars if matched else False 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [94]: is_matched('blah? test', pos=6)                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[94]: True

In [95]: is_matched('blah? test', pos=7)                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[95]: False
```

`.*(\S)(?=\s*$)`:

- `.*` matches any characters upto last non-space character
- `(\S)` matches the last non-space character and put it in a captured group
- The zero-width postive lookahead `(?=\s*$)` makes sure the pattern is followed by zero-more spaces only till end

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want 0 indexed strings

```
def foo(text, pos):
    return text[pos] in ['?','|','!']

foo('blah? test', pos=4) // True
foo('blah? test', pos=5) // False
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex for this. You can very easily use `any` and *list comprehension*.

```
s = 'blah? test'
print(any(v in s[4] for v in '?|!'))
```

Returns `True`.

Changing `s[4]` to `s[5]` results in `False`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex:

```
def foo(s, pos, chars='?|!'):
    for i in range(pos - 1, -1, -1):
        if s[i] == ' ':
            continue
        return s[i] in chars
    return False

print(foo('blah? test', pos=6))
```

If you *had to* use a regex:

```
def foo(s, pos, chars='?|!'):
    l = re.findall(r'[^ ]', s[:pos]) # find all non-blank characters in first pos - 1 characters
    if not l:
        return False
    return l[-1] in chars
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex here. Remove spaces at the end of a slice, if they are, and compare the last char

```
def is_matched(text, pos, chars='?|!'): 
   return text[:pos].rstrip()[-1] in chars

is_matched('blah? test', pos=6) #True
is_matched('blah? test', pos=7) #False
```